# Returned result with value or error

Tags: c#, ajax, json, wcf, exception

First of all, let me explain the current situation.
In a ASP.NET project, we do some ajax calls to a WCF service. This service always returns a value if called. But the way they implemented this, is like this:

```
public Result<string> IDoWhatEverIWant(string parameterExample){
   try{
      //1) Execute code
      //2) Return a value
      return Helper.CreateSuccessMessage<string>("the success value");
   }catch(Exception ex{
      //1) Do some stuff
      //2) Return an error
      return Helper.CreateErrorMessage("The error");
   }
}

public class Result<T>{
    public T Data {get;set;}
    public string Error {get;set;}
}
```

So they always return a "Result" instead of throwing exceptions or returning just the data.

I know this is a personal kind of taste question, but I wonder what are **pro/con arguments** to return a "Result"

Comment: Perhaps this question would be more on-topic at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?  They can answer questions related to software architecture/design, as well as best practices.

Comment: one big issue with this is it will always return 200 ok result even if there is error.